# Sum in range that meet criteria

Tags: python, if-statement, range

Trying to learn a new approach.
It's the classical problem of finding the sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 below 'n'.

What I want is:

```
print ("The sum is: ", sum(range(1, 100)))
```

But with an if-statement for multiples of 3 / 5.
**My question:**
How can I include that if-statement for a one-line solution?

Thanks for your help. =)
// Chris S.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: search in Googe `list comprehensions` - ie, `[x for x in range(1, 100) if ...]`

Comment: Thank you, Furas - this helped me with the solution. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach you may look into:

```
def thesum(the_numbers):
  the_numbers = [i for i in the_numbers if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0]
  return print(sum(the_numbers))

thesum(range(100))
```